# Date difference in R gives numeric value

Tags: r

I can't understand the nature of this computation. Let's say I have a vector of dates:

```
library(lubridate)
dates <- c("2018-12-23 00:02:00", "2018-12-24 00:00:00", "2018-12-25 00:04:00")
```

I would like to subtract 10 seconds from each of these dates. I get numeric output if I use any apply function, however if I do this:

```
ymd_hms(dates[1]) - ms('0,10')
"2018-12-23 00:01:50"
```

I get right answer. How can I get the below output:

```
c("2018-12-23 00:01:50", "2018-12-23 23:59:50", "2018-12-25 00:03:50")
```

Comment: Question is not well written. My guess is you used `sapply`, which converts stuff at the end. You can use `lapply`, or don't `simplify` or simply use the fact that this is vectorized and there is no need to do any `apply`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `seconds` function.

```
library(lubridate)

dates <- c("2018-12-23 00:02:00", "2018-12-24 00:00:00", "2018-12-25 00:04:00")

ymd_hms(dates) - seconds(10)
#[1] "2018-12-23 00:01:50 UTC" "2018-12-23 23:59:50 UTC"
#[3] "2018-12-25 00:03:50 UTC"
```

If you want to subtract several values, possibly different, from `dates` you have to pass a vector to `seconds`.

```
ymd_hms(dates) - seconds(c(5, 10, 15))
#[1] "2018-12-23 00:01:55 UTC" "2018-12-23 23:59:50 UTC"
#[3] "2018-12-25 00:03:45 UTC"
```

Comment: thanks, can i also subtract dynamically? let's say I want to subtract 5, 10, 15 seconds i.e. 5 seconds from first date, 10 from second and so on? how can I do that ?

Answer (score 4):

You could convert to `POSIXct` and subtract `10`

```
dates <- c("2018-12-23 00:02:00", "2018-12-24 00:00:00", "2018-12-25 00:04:00")
as.character(as.POSIXct(dates) - 10)
# [1] "2018-12-23 00:01:50" "2018-12-23 23:59:50" "2018-12-25 00:03:50"
```

From `?DateTimeClasses`

> Class "POSIXct" represents the (signed) number of seconds since the beginning of 1970 (in the UTC time zone) as a numeric vector.

---

If you don't want characters in the end, then just do

```
as.POSIXct(dates) - 10
```

---

As pointed out by @thelatemail we could also do

```
as.POSIXct(dates) - as.difftime(10, units="secs")
```

Possible units are: `"auto", "secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks"`, see `?difftime`.

Comment: Why `as.character`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Good point. Expected output looks like OP wants characters. But I might be wrong about it.

Comment: There's also `as.POSIXct(dates) - as.difftime(10, units="secs")` if you need to specify different units explicitly.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks! This is useful to know.

Answer (score 3):

Your `dates` assignment needs commas... You can skip the `*apply()` approach:

```
library(lubridate)

dates <- ymd_hms(
    c("2018-12-23 00:02:00", "2018-12-24 00:00:00", "2018-12-25 00:04:00")
)

dates - ms("0, 10")

#> [1] "2018-12-23 00:01:50 UTC" "2018-12-23 23:59:50 UTC"
#> [3] "2018-12-25 00:03:50 UTC"
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R

```
strptime(dates, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")-10
[1] "2018-12-23 00:01:50 EST" "2018-12-23 23:59:50 EST" "2018-12-25 00:03:50 EST"
```